# How to bind two tables where the row name of the second table matches the values in a column of the first table?

Tags: r

I am trying to append a table with limits for the values of another table according to the matrix and analyte of the value.

**Table One** has columns including *Matrix* (Fish or Floc), *Analyte* (As, Cd, Cr, Cu, Pb, Hg), and *ResultWet* (numeric values).

**Table Two** has rows for each *Analyte* in Table One and 3 columns, one for the Fish matrix and two for the Floc matrix.

I am trying to figure out how to bind **Table Two** to **Table One** so that each specific combination of Analyte and Matrix will have the corresponding limit value from **Table Two** appended as a new column(s), with rows not meeting the conditions reading *NA*.

The `limit_table` looks like this:

```
limits= matrix(c(30,33,9.79,
                 0.5,4.98,0.99,
                 0.88,111,43.4,
                 300,149,31.6,
                 0.1,1.06,0.18,
                 50,128,35.8), nrow=6, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(limits) = c("fish","floc_PEC","floc_TEC")
rownames(limits) = c("As","Cd","Cr","Cu","Hg","Pb")
limit_table=as.table(limits)
limit_table

     fish floc_PEC floc_TEC
As  30.00    33.00     9.79
Cd   0.50     4.98     0.99
Cr   0.88   111.00    43.40
Cu 300.00   149.00    31.60
Hg   0.10     1.06     0.18
Pb  50.00   128.00    35.80
```

The `Results` table essentially looks like this:

```
setwd("Y:/Luke/HWTT")
Lab_Results <- read.csv(
  file = "Grassy_4.22_Data.csv",
  fileEncoding = 'UTF-8-BOM',
  header  =TRUE,
  sep = ",",
  dec = "."
)
Lab_Results= Lab_Results[c("Sample_Date","Matrix","Analyte","ResultDry","ResultWet","MDLDry","MRLDry","MDLWet","MRLWet","Units")]
Results= Lab_Results[which(Lab_Results$Matrix=='Fish' | Lab_Results$Matrix=="Floc"),]

   Sample_Date Matrix Analyte ResultDry ResultWet  MDLDry   MRLDry   MDLWet   MRLWet Units
1   04/27/2022   Floc     %TS    5.6800   5.68000 0.13000  0.42000 0.130000 0.420000     %
2   04/27/2022   Floc      As    1.9000   0.10800 0.71300  1.66000 0.040000 0.094000 mg/kg
3   04/27/2022   Floc      Cd    0.3170   0.01800 0.31700  0.71300 0.018000 0.040000 mg/kg
4   04/27/2022   Floc      Cr   10.5000   0.59500 7.13000 14.30000 0.405000 0.809000 mg/kg
5   04/27/2022   Floc      Cu    4.2000   0.24000 4.20000  8.40000 0.240000 0.480000 mg/kg
6   04/27/2022   Floc      Pb    3.5300   0.20000 0.71300  2.14000 0.040000 0.121000 mg/kg
7   04/27/2022   Floc      Hg    0.0269   0.00153 0.00563  0.01410 0.000319 0.000799 mg/kg
8   04/29/2022   Fish     %TS   20.5700  20.57000 0.33000  1.09000 0.330000 1.090000     %
9   04/29/2022   Fish      As    0.1620   0.03300 0.03900  0.09200 0.008000 0.019000 mg/kg
10  04/29/2022   Fish      Cd    0.0170   0.00400 0.01700  0.03900 0.004000 0.008000 mg/kg
11  04/29/2022   Fish      Cr    0.8950   0.18400 0.39200  0.78400 0.081000 0.161000 mg/kg
12  04/29/2022   Fish      Cu    7.9700   1.64000 0.23100  0.46200 0.048000 0.095000 mg/kg
13  04/29/2022   Fish      Hg    0.1900   0.03900 0.00308  0.00771 0.000634 0.001590 mg/kg
14  04/29/2022   Fish      Pb    1.3900   0.28700 0.03900  0.11800 0.008000 0.024000 mg/kg
```

I would like the new table to look something like this, with the values for the 3 new columns corresponding to the matrix and analyte or otherwise *NA*:

```
   Sample_Date Matrix Analyte ResultDry ResultWet  MDLDry   MRLDry   MDLWet   MRLWet Units Fish_Limit Floc_PEC Floc_TEC
1   04/27/2022   Floc     %TS    5.6800   5.68000 0.13000  0.42000 0.130000 0.420000     %
2   04/27/2022   Floc      As    1.9000   0.10800 0.71300  1.66000 0.040000 0.094000 mg/kg
3   04/27/2022   Floc      Cd    0.3170   0.01800 0.31700  0.71300 0.018000 0.040000 mg/kg
4   04/27/2022   Floc      Cr   10.5000   0.59500 7.13000 14.30000 0.405000 0.809000 mg/kg
5   04/27/2022   Floc      Cu    4.2000   0.24000 4.20000  8.40000 0.240000 0.480000 mg/kg
6   04/27/2022   Floc      Pb    3.5300   0.20000 0.71300  2.14000 0.040000 0.121000 mg/kg
7   04/27/2022   Floc      Hg    0.0269   0.00153 0.00563  0.01410 0.000319 0.000799 mg/kg
8   04/29/2022   Fish     %TS   20.5700  20.57000 0.33000  1.09000 0.330000 1.090000     %
9   04/29/2022   Fish      As    0.1620   0.03300 0.03900  0.09200 0.008000 0.019000 mg/kg
10  04/29/2022   Fish      Cd    0.0170   0.00400 0.01700  0.03900 0.004000 0.008000 mg/kg
11  04/29/2022   Fish      Cr    0.8950   0.18400 0.39200  0.78400 0.081000 0.161000 mg/kg
12  04/29/2022   Fish      Cu    7.9700   1.64000 0.23100  0.46200 0.048000 0.095000 mg/kg
13  04/29/2022   Fish      Hg    0.1900   0.03900 0.00308  0.00771 0.000634 0.001590 mg/kg
14  04/29/2022   Fish      Pb    1.3900   0.28700 0.03900  0.11800 0.008000 0.024000 mg/kg
```

**Edit:**

I reformatted the `limit_table` to make the row names into a new column called *Analyte* and merged the table to the first table with *Analyte* as the `by=` operator:

```
limits= matrix(c("As",30,33,9.79,
                 "Cd",0.5,4.98,0.99,
                 "Cr",0.88,111,43.4,
                 "Cu",300,149,31.6,
                 "Hg",0.1,1.06,0.18,
                 "Pb",50,128,35.8), nrow=6, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(limits) = c("Analyte","Fish_Limit","Floc_PEC","Floc_TEC")
limits
Results= merge(Results,limits,by='Analyte', all.x=TRUE)
```

However, there is no way I can see to only add the *Fish_Limit* column to rows that include the Fish *Matrix* value and the Floc_PEC and Floc_TEC columns to the rows that have the Floc *Matrix*. Is there any way to include that extra step?

Here is a part of the new table so far:

```
> Results
   Analyte Sample_Date Matrix ResultDry ResultWet  MDLDry   MRLDry   MDLWet   MRLWet Units Fish_Limit Floc_PEC Floc_TEC
1      %TS  04/27/2022   Floc    5.6800   5.68000 0.13000  0.42000 0.130000 0.420000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
2      %TS  04/27/2022   Floc    5.2100   5.21000 0.14000  0.45000 0.140000 0.450000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
3      %TS  04/27/2022   Floc    5.2700   5.27000 0.13000  0.45000 0.130000 0.450000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
4      %TS  04/29/2022   Fish   21.8700  21.87000 0.28000  0.94000 0.280000 0.940000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
5      %TS  04/29/2022   Fish   21.9800  21.98000 0.28000  0.92000 0.280000 0.920000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
6      %TS  04/29/2022   Fish   21.9200  21.92000 0.30000  1.00000 0.300000 1.000000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
7      %TS  04/29/2022   Fish   20.2800  20.28000 0.31000  1.02000 0.310000 1.020000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
8      %TS  04/29/2022   Fish   20.5700  20.57000 0.33000  1.09000 0.330000 1.090000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
9      %TS  04/29/2022   Fish   20.9800  20.98000 0.33000  1.10000 0.330000 1.100000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
10     %TS  04/29/2022   Fish   20.8200  20.82000 0.34000  1.12000 0.340000 1.120000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
11     %TS  04/29/2022   Fish   21.2000  21.20000 0.29000  0.96000 0.290000 0.960000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
12     %TS  04/29/2022   Fish   21.5300  21.53000 0.28000  0.95000 0.280000 0.950000     %       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
13      As  04/29/2022   Fish    0.1240   0.02700 0.04100  0.09500 0.009000 0.021000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
14      As  04/29/2022   Fish    0.1560   0.03400 0.04000  0.09300 0.009000 0.020000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
15      As  04/27/2022   Floc    1.9000   0.10800 0.71300  1.66000 0.040000 0.094000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
16      As  04/27/2022   Floc    2.3200   0.12100 0.75800  1.77000 0.040000 0.092000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
17      As  04/27/2022   Floc    2.3900   0.12600 0.79700  1.86000 0.042000 0.098000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
18      As  04/29/2022   Fish    0.1640   0.03600 0.03800  0.09000 0.008000 0.020000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
19      As  04/29/2022   Fish    0.1550   0.03400 0.04000  0.09400 0.009000 0.021000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
20      As  04/29/2022   Fish    0.1780   0.03700 0.04000  0.09200 0.008000 0.019000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
21      As  04/29/2022   Fish    0.1600   0.03200 0.03900  0.09200 0.008000 0.019000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
22      As  04/29/2022   Fish    0.1620   0.03300 0.03900  0.09200 0.008000 0.019000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
23      As  04/29/2022   Fish    0.1700   0.03600 0.04000  0.09400 0.008000 0.020000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
24      As  04/29/2022   Fish    0.1330   0.02800 0.04200  0.09700 0.009000 0.021000 mg/kg         30       33     9.79
25      Cd  04/29/2022   Fish    0.0180   0.00400 0.01800  0.04000 0.004000 0.009000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
26      Cd  04/29/2022   Fish    0.0180   0.00400 0.01800  0.04100 0.004000 0.009000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
27      Cd  04/29/2022   Fish    0.0180   0.00400 0.01800  0.04200 0.004000 0.009000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
28      Cd  04/29/2022   Fish    0.0180   0.00400 0.01800  0.04000 0.004000 0.009000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
29      Cd  04/27/2022   Floc    0.3170   0.01800 0.31700  0.71300 0.018000 0.040000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
30      Cd  04/27/2022   Floc    0.3370   0.01800 0.33700  0.75800 0.018000 0.040000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
31      Cd  04/27/2022   Floc    0.3540   0.01900 0.35400  0.79700 0.019000 0.042000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
32      Cd  04/29/2022   Fish    0.0170   0.00400 0.01700  0.03800 0.004000 0.008000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
33      Cd  04/29/2022   Fish    0.0180   0.00400 0.01800  0.04000 0.004000 0.008000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
34      Cd  04/29/2022   Fish    0.0180   0.00400 0.01800  0.04000 0.004000 0.008000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
35      Cd  04/29/2022   Fish    0.0170   0.00400 0.01700  0.03900 0.004000 0.008000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
36      Cd  04/29/2022   Fish    0.0170   0.00400 0.01700  0.03900 0.004000 0.008000 mg/kg        0.5     4.98     0.99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `limits` object is a data.frame (see input below), you can do this, using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

Results %>% 
  left_join(
    bind_rows(
      limits %>% mutate(Matrix = "Fish") %>% mutate(Floc_PEC = NA, Floc_TEC=NA),
      limits %>% mutate(Matrix = "Floc") %>% mutate(Fish_Limit = NA)
  )
)
```

Output:

```
   Sample_Date Matrix Analyte ResultDry ResultWet  MDLDry   MRLDry   MDLWet   MRLWet Units Fish_Limit Floc_PEC Floc_TEC
1   04/27/2022   Floc     %TS    5.6800   5.68000 0.13000  0.42000 0.130000 0.420000     %         NA       NA       NA
2   04/27/2022   Floc      As    1.9000   0.10800 0.71300  1.66000 0.040000 0.094000 mg/kg         NA    33.00     9.79
3   04/27/2022   Floc      Cd    0.3170   0.01800 0.31700  0.71300 0.018000 0.040000 mg/kg         NA     4.98     0.99
4   04/27/2022   Floc      Cr   10.5000   0.59500 7.13000 14.30000 0.405000 0.809000 mg/kg         NA   111.00    43.40
5   04/27/2022   Floc      Cu    4.2000   0.24000 4.20000  8.40000 0.240000 0.480000 mg/kg         NA   149.00    31.60
6   04/27/2022   Floc      Pb    3.5300   0.20000 0.71300  2.14000 0.040000 0.121000 mg/kg         NA   128.00    35.80
7   04/27/2022   Floc      Hg    0.0269   0.00153 0.00563  0.01410 0.000319 0.000799 mg/kg         NA     1.06     0.18
8   04/29/2022   Fish     %TS   20.5700  20.57000 0.33000  1.09000 0.330000 1.090000     %         NA       NA       NA
9   04/29/2022   Fish      As    0.1620   0.03300 0.03900  0.09200 0.008000 0.019000 mg/kg      30.00       NA       NA
10  04/29/2022   Fish      Cd    0.0170   0.00400 0.01700  0.03900 0.004000 0.008000 mg/kg       0.50       NA       NA
11  04/29/2022   Fish      Cr    0.8950   0.18400 0.39200  0.78400 0.081000 0.161000 mg/kg       0.88       NA       NA
12  04/29/2022   Fish      Cu    7.9700   1.64000 0.23100  0.46200 0.048000 0.095000 mg/kg     300.00       NA       NA
13  04/29/2022   Fish      Hg    0.1900   0.03900 0.00308  0.00771 0.000634 0.001590 mg/kg       0.10       NA       NA
14  04/29/2022   Fish      Pb    1.3900   0.28700 0.03900  0.11800 0.008000 0.024000 mg/kg      50.00       NA       NA
```

Inputs:

```
limits = structure(list(Analyte = c("As", "Cd", "Cr", "Cu", "Hg", "Pb"
), Fish_Limit = c(30, 0.5, 0.88, 300, 0.1, 50), Floc_PEC = c(33, 
4.98, 111, 149, 1.06, 128), Floc_TEC = c(9.79, 0.99, 43.4, 31.6, 
0.18, 35.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

Results = structure(list(Sample_Date = c("04/27/2022", "04/27/2022", "04/27/2022", 
"04/27/2022", "04/27/2022", "04/27/2022", "04/27/2022", "04/29/2022", 
"04/29/2022", "04/29/2022", "04/29/2022", "04/29/2022", "04/29/2022", 
"04/29/2022"), Matrix = c("Floc", "Floc", "Floc", "Floc", "Floc", 
"Floc", "Floc", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", "Fish", 
"Fish"), Analyte = c("%TS", "As", "Cd", "Cr", "Cu", "Pb", "Hg", 
"%TS", "As", "Cd", "Cr", "Cu", "Hg", "Pb"), ResultDry = c(5.68, 
1.9, 0.317, 10.5, 4.2, 3.53, 0.0269, 20.57, 0.162, 0.017, 0.895, 
7.97, 0.19, 1.39), ResultWet = c(5.68, 0.108, 0.018, 0.595, 0.24, 
0.2, 0.00153, 20.57, 0.033, 0.004, 0.184, 1.64, 0.039, 0.287), 
    MDLDry = c(0.13, 0.713, 0.317, 7.13, 4.2, 0.713, 0.00563, 
    0.33, 0.039, 0.017, 0.392, 0.231, 0.00308, 0.039), MRLDry = c(0.42, 
    1.66, 0.713, 14.3, 8.4, 2.14, 0.0141, 1.09, 0.092, 0.039, 
    0.784, 0.462, 0.00771, 0.118), MDLWet = c(0.13, 0.04, 0.018, 
    0.405, 0.24, 0.04, 0.000319, 0.33, 0.008, 0.004, 0.081, 0.048, 
    0.000634, 0.008), MRLWet = c(0.42, 0.094, 0.04, 0.809, 0.48, 
    0.121, 0.000799, 1.09, 0.019, 0.008, 0.161, 0.095, 0.00159, 
    0.024), Units = c("%", "mg/kg", "mg/kg", "mg/kg", "mg/kg", 
    "mg/kg", "mg/kg", "%", "mg/kg", "mg/kg", "mg/kg", "mg/kg", 
    "mg/kg", "mg/kg")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```